# Can you solve $y'(x) = y^2(x)\;\land\;y(x_0) = y_0 $ on $]-1, 1[$ using the Banach contraction theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, cauchy-problem

I would like to solve the following Cauchy problem:

$$
\begin{cases}
y'(x) = y^2(x)\\
y(x_0) = y_0
\end{cases}\tag 1
$$
In my opinion, using the [Banach contraction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) it can only be solved in $I:= \ ]-1, 1[$ since:

$$\forall x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R: |x_1^2 - x_2^2 | < |x_1 -x_2| \Longrightarrow x_1, x_2 \in I \tag 2$$

In that puprose, $x_0$ must also be in $I$. Is my reasonment correct ?

Comment: You can solve this directly via separation-of-variables, which would make the contraction construction trivial. Your opinion is wrong, as you only get $|x_1+x_2|\le 2$ on this interval. But why would that be important, the square is in $y$. Look again at the details of the construction of the domain for the fixed-point iteration.

Comment: "why would that be important, the square is in y" - I didn't understand this part

Comment: First a question, is $y^2$ the square of $y$ or is it $y^2(x)=y(y(x))$? // In this problem formulation, $x$ stands for the domain and $y$ for the range. The inequality is irrelevant for the domain. It might be relevant for the Lipschitz condition in the range, in $y$ variables. There is something called "the principle of least surprise".

Comment: $y^2$ is the square of $y$. In my book, it is written that for $y' = f(x,y)$, the Picard operator $T$ is a contraction if (among others) $f(x, y)$ is $\Lambda$-lipshitzian. Maybe my confusion is that I thought I needed $\Lambda < 1$, which is not true ($\ell.\Lambda = \alpha < 1$ with $\ell$ the width of the domain around $x_0$ where the problem is solved)

Comment: You need $ℓ.Λ<1$ for the normal supremum norm. But for all $Λ$ there is a weighted supremum norm so that the contraction factor is $1/2$ independent of the interval length.